# How to limit a 350W rated electric motor to 200W

Tags: motor

How can one, in a straightforward way, limit a 350W rated electric motor to 200W?

There is only a single DC motor. 36V I think.

The load may approach, at times, the maximum rated value.

Comment: More information required. Is the load even heavy enough that the motor tries to output its rated value?

Comment: It depends on what kind of motor is used, what you mean by "limit," how the load reacts, what kind of load reaction is acceptable, what you consider "straightforward," what accuracy and speed of reaction is required, and probably other considerations. The motor needs an appropriate electronic controller and a means of measuring motor power. If you buy the right motor & controller package, you install it and configure and tune it to do what you want it to do.

Comment: If you edit the question to include more information I will withdraw my vote to close and try to get the question re-opened. But as it stands it isn't really answerable.

Comment: Current limiting & PWM works but with no specs, no details

Comment: If it is not driving a load, does it take 350W?

Answer (score 1):

Limit the voltage.

Let's say your 350W motor is rated for 70V.  That means when you apply 70V AND apply the right load torque (somewhere in the middle of the holding torque and no-load torque) the motor will be outputting 350W of power.  At all other torques, the output power will be less.  It's like an upside down parabola.

If you apply 60V, the curve looks the same, but the peak has a little less power.

So what I'm trying to say is, find a voltage where the output power at ideal torque is 200W, and just understand that at other torques it will be even less.

Side note: this is only very weakly associated with input electrical power efficiency.  You won't be at your most efficient operating point.

Comment: A resistor won't work, you also need to specify if this is an AC or DC motor